# ArrayList<Int> Collections.Sort and LineNumberReader Help How to

Tags: java

I have a issue i can't get it to work now let going to the point a explain in the code thanks.

This is my class: what I want to do is insert the Integers sort the list and buffer writer in a column with out coma. Now I getting this: 
[1110018, 1110032, 1110056, 1110059, 1110063, 1110085, 1110096, 1110123, 1110125, 1110185, 1110456, 1110459]

I want like this:
111xxxxx
111xxxx
xxxx.......

I can't do it in single array, have to be in ArrayList.
This is my collecting:
 list.addNumbers(numbers);
 list.display();

This is my writer: Is buffered
coma.write("\n"+list.display());
 
  coma.flush();

****public class IdCount {
  private ArrayList properNumber = new ArrayList<>();

```
 public void addNumbers(Integer numbers) {<br/>
properNumber.add(numbers);**<br/>
```

Collections.sort(properNumber);
    }
     public String display() {
(I try .toString() Not work)
            return properNumber.toString();

```
      }**
```

My second issue is LineNumberReader: This is my collecting and my writing: 
try {
            Reader input = new BufferedReader( new FileReader(inputFile));
            try (Scanner in = new Scanner(input)) {
                while (in.hasNext()) {
                   (More Code)
                    asp = new LineNumberReader(input);   
                    int rom = 0;

```
              while (asp.readLine()!=null){<br/>
                  rom++;<br/>
              }
          System.out.println(rom);<br/>coma.write(rom);<br/>
```

This one not write anything an my System Print give me only 12 0 in column.
Thank you for the help in advances. Any help it will appreciate.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for how markdown works on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I want like this:

111xxxxx

111xxxx

xxxx.......*

Then in write your display method as follows:

```
public String display() {
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  Iterator i = properNumber.iterator();
  while(i.hasNext()){
   sb.append(i.next);
   sb.append("\n");
  }

  return sb.toString();
}
```

Explanation:

**What you were doing :**

`return properNumber.toString();` will return a string that contains all values inside `properNumber` comma-seperated. so thats why you were getting that output.

**What I have done**

Made a `StringBuilder` object so that I can temporarily store the strings before returning all the values.

Then I made a iterator that iterates through  `properNumber` and then append each entry to the `StringBuilder` object and appending `\n` after it.

Finally when the iterator completes meaning I have added all entries inside `properNumber` in `StringBuilder` object `sb`. So now I will return the content of `sb` as `String` using `sb.toString()` method.

Comment: That put me very closed. The "/n" is not working, maybe because I BufferedWriter out,I will found the reason. The "/n" is not working in any of the writing. I been using .newLine();

Comment: @user1819551 hope you understood how to use iterators